# sortable images after upload - jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-ui-sortable, blueimp

Is there an easy way to add dragging/sorting functionality that would allow us to re-order the images after they've been uploaded

like this:
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder

or like this:
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

Answer (score 2):

ya they can be made sortable..just add this in the end

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( ".files" ).sortable({
            revert: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I used blueimp and I used DataList.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upImages" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="fileupload" style="float:left">
            <div class="fileupload-content">
                <asp:DataList ID="ImageList" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" DataKeyField="Index" OnItemDataBound="ImageList_ItemDataBound"
                 OnItemCommand="ImageList_ItemCommand" HorizontalAlign="Justify">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <tbody class="files">
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <td class="preview" style="float:left;"><img id="imglegend"  src="<%#Eval("ImageURL")%>" /></td>
                        <td class="name" style="display: none"><label id="imgSavePath" target="_blank" title="<%#Eval("ImageFullURL")%>"></label></td>
                                  ...                                    
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </tbody> 
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
            </div>
            <div width="500px" style="float:left">
                <span width="50px">Pick photos...</span>
                <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" title="Bladeren" multiple />
            </div>         
        </div>     
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Add sortable property on DataList.
      $("#<%=ImageList.ClientID%> tbody").sortable();
template-upload is commented because it is killing the drag and drop because there is so many hidden rows in table generated. 
Hope I helped.